# acf_add_option() is not showing any option in admin dashboard

Tags: php

[image]

I am trying to add the option in the Wordpress admin dashboard I am using advance custom field. This is my function.php code.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you should add code instead of image

Comment: Just in add of @BilalAhmed, add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code))not images. Images A) don't allow us to copy-paste the code/errors/data for testing B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.